# Any tips how I can draw this layout in Java swing and Awt

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I am trying to draw a layout which is like below image. I try it from yesterday night, but I could not made it yet. Any idea How I can draw such layout in Java swing

[image: This is the Image Similar like to draw]

I try to draw with `GridLayout` and also `GridBagLayout` but really I did not get it yet.

Comment: Maybe two `BorderLayout`s, a `BorderLayout` and `GridBagLayout` or just a `GridBagLayout`...

Answer (score 1):

This is a pure `GridBagLayout` implementation, but it would be possible to use a `BorderLayout` and place the three top panels into their own `JPanel` (using `GridBagLayout`) a place that into the `CENTER` with the bottom panel in the `SOUTH` position...

[image: Layout]

```
setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

JPanel main = createPanel(400, 400, Color.RED);
JPanel menu = createPanel(600, 100, Color.BLUE);
JPanel upper = createPanel(200, 300, Color.GREEN);
JPanel lower = createPanel(200, 100, Color.MAGENTA);

GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 0;
gbc.gridheight = 2;
gbc.weightx = 1;
gbc.weighty = 1;
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
add(main, gbc);

gbc.gridx++;
gbc.gridy = 0;
gbc.gridheight = 1;
gbc.weightx = 0;
gbc.weighty = 0;
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
add(upper, gbc);

gbc.gridy++;
add(lower, gbc);

gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy++;
gbc.gridwidth = 2;
gbc.weightx = 1;
add(menu, gbc);
```

Comment: Hmmm..  You're obviously going to [beat me to 500](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/layout-manager/topusers). ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson If I get very, very lucky, no one will ask any more layout questions :P